# Meaning of 「全て込めて解き放て」 in this song ("Brand New World" by Shiena Nishizawa)

Tags: translation, meaning, song-lyrics

In the song [Brand New World](http://www.lyrical-nonsense.com/lyrics/shiena-nishizawa/brand-new-world/) by Shiena Nishizawa, this part

> 泣き叫んで　顔を出した　弱さの化身も
>
> 全て込めて解き放て　Brand-new World

Was translated as

> Even the incarnation of weakness, showing its face with a scream –
> I'll release everything right here and now: A Brand-new World!

1. What is 「込めて」 doing here?
2. Where does "right here and now" come from?

I checked [込める](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B) and [解き放つ](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%8D%E6%94%BE%E3%81%A4) on Jisho.org and didn't find anything that would explain this usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first (or second) definition on jisho.org applies. 込める here is to charge, or to put energy into some container. Imagine something like a [元気玉](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_Bomb), to which you can put negative emotions until it bursts.
2. It's a free translation, and "right here and now" comes from nowhere. Literally, the sentence is only saying "Charge everything (that I mentioned in the previous line) and release it".